# Select2 data from wordpress custom table using AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am using `select2`**[v:4.0.6](https://select2.org)** and ajax call to search wordpress custom table. But search field is showing any value when I check in console I found error message like
`NO result found`
I am not sure but maybe I did mistake on my ajax call. can someone help me to fix this issue.

**Note:** I declare all `enqueue_scripts` correctly.

**To show `select2` field**

```
<select id="bRsearch" class="js-data-brname-ajax"></select>
```

**Here is My ajax**

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Search Branch Code with select2 plugin   
     var ajaxurl =  SBLAjax.ajaxurl;
     $("select#bRsearch").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {

                var query = {
                    q: params.term,
                    action: 'branchsearch2', // AJAX action for admin-ajax.php
              }
              return query;
            },
            cache: true
        },
    });
  });   
})( jQuery );
```

**And PHP Function for this ajax call**

```
function branchsearch2() {
global $wpdb;
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."sbl_br_name";
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT s.br_name, s.br_code "
            . "FROM wp_sbl_br_name s "
            . "WHERE s.br_name LIKE '%" . $q . "%' "
            . "OR s.br_code LIKE '%" . $q . "%' "
        );

    $data = array();

    if (is_array($rows)) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) { 
            $code = $row->br_code;
            $text = $row->br_name;
            $data[] = array('id' => $code, 'text' => $text);
        }
    }
    return json_encode($data);
//--------------------------------------
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_branchsearch2', 'branchsearch2' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_branchsearch2', 'branchsearch2' );
```

Comment: check what does `var_dump( $q );` returns ?

Comment: It return data a branch of data array... I have checked

Comment: can you update answer posting what the `var_dump( $q )` returns?

Comment: this what i gfet from ajax response `[{"id":"55285","text":"NAME OF THE BRANCH"}]`